# lint error - Array prototype is read only, properties should not be added

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I am getting lint error when I use the below code in my application..

Array prototype is read only, properties should not be added  no-extend-native
Use the spread operator instead of '.apply()'    .. please advise

```
Array.prototype.pushArray = function(arr) {
  this.push.apply(this, arr);
};
```

Comment: Check this article https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/blob/master/message-articles/extending-native.md

Comment: it's considered bad practice to add custom property to native js objects that will effect globally

Answer (score 1):

May use .concat? :

```
array = array.concat(whatever)
```

or the spread operator:

```
array.push(...whatever)
```

While your code works, js performance is determined through how predictable your code is. The more predictable, the faster it gets. Overriding the native prototypes ( and any prototypes at all) removes that predictability and makes your code more slow. Thats why it isnt recommended ( as well as its dangerous, as a single mistake can change the behaviour of the overall code...)

Answer (score 1):

It wants you to use the spread operator instead of apply, so try this:

```
Array.prototype.pushArray = function(arr) {
  this.push(...arr);
};
```

You may still have a linting problem for the fact that you're extending the array prototype at all. If that's the case and you really want to do it anyway, then you can modify your linting rules, or add an exception.